Ruby debugging will not work in VSCode for any of the debuggers
I am trying to debug a ruby program and cant get the debugger to work for ANY of the debuggers. I have tried rdbg, pry-byebug, byebug and LSP. Every time I try to run the bebugger it says DEBUGGER : Disconnected. I am using the standard launch,json for each debugger type as well as using the required tag when I'm using pry, pry-byebug or debug. I can't seem to get anything to work. I have set breakpoints by using binding.pry, binding.byebug and regular F9 breakpoints.
I tried using pry-byebug, pry, rdbg and LSP to start the debugger. I also created a launch.json file for rdbg and LSP, though both are obviously not used at the same time. I have use the required tag for each of the debuggers that required them as well as adding the gems that are required. I have also set the PATH: to the correct path to the rdbg executable.
